# Debugging on the Device

Tags: android, debugging

I have a problem - my app works fine on the simulator, but on the device it crashes.  Is there a way to debug an app that is running on the phone?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible. Just use Eclipse and register your device for debug use.

The procedure is a little bit different with each device, but you will basically need to put your device USB connection in **debug mode** and run your program/project within Eclipse IDE.